# reading the media namespace from a flickr rss feed

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-7, flickr

I am trying to read `<media:content>...</media:content>` from a flickr feed but i'm not sure how to access it. I am trying to use XNamespace but I think I have got it quite wrong.

```
XNamespace media = "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/";

foreach (XElement value in doc.Element("rss").Element("channel").Elements("item"))
{
    flick _item = new flick();

    _item.title = value.Element("title").Value;
    _item.link = value.Element("link").Value;
    _item.pubDate = DateTime.Parse(value.Element("pubDate").Value);
    _item.imagecontent = value.Element(media + "content").Value;

    flicks.Add(_item);
}
```

Comment: It seems everything should be ok. This is a standard way of reading elements with namespaces using linq to xml.

Comment: i have been stupid, I am reading value but it's a singleton tag so I should be reading attributes from the tag instead.